# Diagonalizable maps commute? What went wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization

This seems weird: If $T: V \rightarrow V$ is diagonalizable linear operator on finite dimensional vector space $V$, and $S:V \rightarrow V$ is another linear operator, then take basis $B$ for which $[T]_B$ is diagonal matrix. Do we not have

$[TS]_B= [T]_B [S]_B = [S]_B [T]_B =[ST]_B$ hence $ST=TS$? What went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not simply mistaken, then you're probably trying to remember one of:

- *Scalar operators* — operators that are scalar multiples of the identity — commute with every matrix.
- *Simultaneously diagonalizable operators* — a pair of operators that are both diagonal relative to a single basis — commute.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that diagonal matrices only commute with every other matrix when all of the diagonal elements are equal, that is, when they are multiples of the identity. $T$ is only given as diagonalizable, so we don’t know whether or not all of its eigenvalues are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Why would a diagonal matrix commutes with another matrix? Take for example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

In other words, your computation went wrong here:
$$[T]_B[S]_B=[S]_B[T]_B.$$

Comment: Your wording seems a little strange - I certainly wouldn't agree that your second matrix is diagonal. If you mean that the second matrix is diagonalizable, and that the basis with respect to which it is diagonalizable is different from the first, then I agree (but I think that's the important thing to stress!)

Comment: The OP never stated that $S$ must be diagonal or diagonalizable, it is any linear map, which is worst.

Comment: Ah... serious mistake...question is quite bad, shall I delete the post? I was assuming any diagonal matrix commute...

Comment: Ah, I see! Sorry, by "another one" I thought you meant "another diagonal matrix"

Comment: @CWL It is okay to make mistakes, don't sweat it. :) You have three answers to your question, I don't think you should delete your post.